# Мертвые соединения?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Это нормально, что если сделать `Open` с одним `ConnectionString`, а затем сделать `Close`, поменять `ConnectionString`(Например, сменить AppName) и снова открыть, то в `sys.dm_exec_sessions` будет висеть, как новое соединение, так и старое?
Можно ли этого избежать?

Comment: Это не мертвые соединения, это соединения из пула